# Javascript: Automatically select all the options of select-box multiple is not working

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I try without success to select automatically with javascript all the options of a select-box multiple before submitting the form with POST. When the user select himself all the elements of the box, the elements are sent with POST. But I don't want the user to do that every time, that is why i want to do it automatically with a script.

here is the form: (The select box has no option at the beginning)

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post" id ="myForm"> 

    ...

 <select name="bestellung[]" id="myList" size="9" multiple>

 </select>

 <button type="button" id="".$this->pizzaName."" data-preis="".$this->preis."" onclick="im_korb('".$this->pizzaName."');"></button>


<div>

  <table>

    <tr>
       <td> <label for="name">Name :</label> </td>
       <td> <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder=" Ihr Name" 
           size="40" required/> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
       <td> <label for="adresse">Lieferadresse :</label> </td>
       <td> <input type="text" name="adresse" id="adresse" placeholder=" Ihre Adresse" 
           size="40" required/> </td>
    </tr>

  </table>

</div>

  ...

   <div id="button3">
     <input type="submit" value="Bestellen">
   </div>

</form>
```

Then I use this script to add many options in a select box:

```
function im_korb(pizza){       

 var selectList = document.getElementById("myList");
 var Button = document.getElementById(pizza);

 var newOption = document.createElement('option');
     newOption.text = pizza.toString();
     newOption.value = pizza.toString();     

 selectList.add(newOption);

}
```

Then I submit the form using this script:(But it is still not sending the elements when the user don't select them himself)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#myForm').on('submit', function() {

    /* Here I try to select all the options of the selectbox
       before sending the elements with POST, but it is not working*/

    var selectList = document.getElementById("myList");

    for (var i=0; i< selectList.options.length; i++) {

     // should select all the options but it is not working
      selectList.options[i].selected = true; 

    }       

    var name = $('#name').val();
    var adresse = $('#adresse').val();
    var bestellung = $('#myList').val();

    $.post( "insert.php", {name: name, adresse: adresse , bestellung: bestellung}, function(data){ 

        alert('Erfolgreiche Bestellung');

    });

    document.getElementById("name").value='';
    document.getElementById("adresse").value='';    
    document.getElementById("myList").options.length = 0;   

    return false; 
}); });
```

Here is the part of the page "insert.php" who receive the elements sending with POST:

```
foreach ( sanitize($_POST['bestellung']) as $pizza)
        {
            $query = "INSERT INTO bestelltePizza(fBestellungID, fPizzaName, Status) VALUES ('$idLezteBestellung', '$pizza','bestellt')";
            $database->query($query);
        }
```

When the user do not select the options, nothing are sent using POST. But I try without success to select them autommatically before sending them.

Please Help.

Comment: Try this $('#myList option').prop('selected', true);
please write all the code in either JS or jquery, dont mix it like that.

Comment: Why not creating an array? Var bestellungen =[]. Whenever im_korb is called do bestellungen.push(pizza); And then send that array to server.

Comment: Thanks to you people. These solutions are working. my own code too. When i clear the cache of my browser everything works like i was waiting.